# Why is WordPress so popular?

Tags: wordpress, joomla

I have been creating joomla-powered webiste for quite a while by now. Recently I had to do a makeover of a WordPress powered website that also included significant navigation and structure changes. Perhaps it is that I am so used to Joomla, but WordPress seemed so damn not cool. Like simply listing pages requires either installing a plugin or dipping into documentation and coding it yourself, while you can easily accomplish it with just a few clicks in Joomla. Then in Joomla I can specify what modules I want to be shown for certain menu items or even assign a different theme if I need to. In WordPress I had to write some php code to accomplish this trivial task. It is so natural and easy to code themes with jdoc statements it took me half an hour to grasp everything when I tried doing it the very first time, and it took me hours to sort everything out with WordPress. I mean, yup, Joomla isn't perfect too, e.g. they still haven't updated documentation for 1.6 and stuff.

But why do people love WordPress so much?! I could understand using it for blogs, but why would anyone use it to build full-fledged web-sites?

Comment: This question doesn't belong here, but, its popularity comes from the fact that people use it for blog, I don't think it's as popular when you take blogs out of the consideration. You seem to push Joomla though, in that case, why wouldn't you use Drupal instead? It's better.

Comment: 1) cuz I have a life 2) my job is more into creating themes than programming and while there are those nice things like views and  taxonomy, theme developping in drupal is a total turn off and a timer-eater. Besides, for custom\perfomance-oriented website we have a Yii developper.

Comment: I'm actually making a theme to Drupal from a psd as we speak, it's so easy I can even browse SO while I'm doing it.

Comment: Joomla is horrendously difficult to extend. Personally, I avoid it like the plague. WordPress makes it simple. Extensibility plays a huge role in WP's success.